# Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in

Tags: php, wordpress, warnings

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in  /wp-content/plugins/nd-booking/inc/shortcodes/include/search-results/nd_booking_post_preview-1.php on line 133

Answer (score 0):

```
                            if( is_numeric( $nd_booking_trip_price ) ){

                                $nd_booking_trip_price = (int) $nd_booking_trip_price + (int) nd_booking_get_final_price($nd_booking_id,$nd_booking_date_cicle);

                                $nd_booking_date_cicle = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($nd_booking_date_cicle.' + 1 days'));

                                $nd_booking_index++;

                            }
```

Comment: Add your code to your original post, not as an answer.